# Reset Backbone.Collections in Backbone.Model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model which holds a default object with some Backbone.Collections. I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but it suits my needs for now. However, when a new instance of the Model is created, the Collections aren't reset, but new models are added. Should the defaults not be reset automagically? I now have to set myColls in the initialize function.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        'someProp': '',
         'myColls': {
            'first': new Backbone.Collection(),
            'second': new Backbone.Collection(),
            'third': new Backbone.Collection()
         }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // This does reset myColls:
        this.set('myColls', {
            'first': new Backbone.Collection(),
            'second': new Backbone.Collection(),
            'third': new Backbone.Collection()
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in Backbone documentation on [Model.defaults](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults)

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if
>   you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all
>   instances. Instead, define defaults as a function.

So,

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            'someProp': '',
            'myColls': {
                'first': new Backbone.Collection(),
                'second': new Backbone.Collection(),
                'third': new Backbone.Collection()
             }
        };
    },
    initialize: function() {
    }
});
```